# A dealer who professes to sell his goods at cost price uses a $900$ gm weight for a kg. His gain percentage is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> A dealer who professes to sell his goods at cost price uses a $900$ gm weight for a kg. His gain percentage is
>
> a. $9$
>
> b. $10$
>
> c. $11$
>
> d. $11.11$

Correct answer is $11.11\%$ but how the dealer is gaining. According to me answer must be that he is losing $10\%$ since he is losing $100$gm weights while selling his good. Please if anyone can help me with this question

Comment: If you only get 900 g when you pay for 1 kg, who has lost? The seller or you?

Comment: In your question are you comparing the decrease of the 900 g weight to the 1000 g weight? Please clarify your language - it's very overcomplicated.

Comment: If that is the case you can apply the formula of *percentage change* = $\frac{new - old}{old}$ and substitute the values in. When you are comparing the 100 g change, you have compared it to the new value instead of the old value - we are comparing the change in weight to the original value only.

Comment: There is another question which says weighing balance shows 900gm for 1kg. In this case seller is  losing.@Henrik

Comment: That's the other way around. In that case, the customer only pays for 900g, but recieves 1kg. I can see how it's difficult to keep track of this. The important things to keep in mind is how much is actually bought, and what weight the price is based off of.

Comment: The percentage change formula is important - in my opinion it is easy to lose track of what you are comparing *to*, so this is not a factual mistake, but a conceptual one.

Comment: @Arthur Can you please explain it a bit more? I am really confused

Comment: If he is using a weight that says "1kg", but only weighs 900g, then the customer gets less than he pays for. That's this question. If I understood your desciption of the other question correctly, the weighing balance shows 900g when it really is 1kg. In that case, the customer gets more than he pays for.

Answer (score 1):

The dealer is not "losing" $100$g in each sale.  Rather the dealer is getting the cost of $1$kg $= 1000$g of goods but delivering only $900$g because of the improper weight used.

The percentage gain $11.11$% comes from the denominator (money per weight) being smaller than it should be.  A $90$% smaller denominator gives a $10/9$ multiple of the ratio (money per weight).

Since $10/9 \approx 111.11$%, that answer is closest to the true value.

Comment: The weighing balance shows 900 gm for 1 kg. Why in this question dealer is losing 10%? @hardmath

Comment: Now you are changing the problem, as you yourself noted in the comments under the original Question.  In one case the dealer uses a 900g weight when telling the buyer they are purchasing 1kg, so the dealer *shortchanges* the buyer.  In the other problem the scale reads 900g when the actual weight of goods on the scale is 1kg.  In this case the buyer would pay for 900g when receiving a full kilogram, and the dealer gets shortchanged.

Comment: I have been confused by the numerator and denominator many times!